# MVVM viewmodel being called twice but only once when debugging?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, mvvm-light

I have a windows phone 7 app and I'm using mvvm light for my view model. I have a MainPage and the view model is MainViewModel;

In My view model I have something like this

```
Public MainViewModel()
{
    if(IsInDesignMode)
    {
        // blah blah
    }
    else
    {
       MediaLibrary ml = new MediaLibrary();
       Songs = ml.Songs;
       ArtisList = ml.Artists;
       PlayLists = ml.Playlists;

       foreach(Album a in ml.Albums)
            MyAlbums.Add(new AlbumItem(a));

        GetCurrentSongInfo();

        MessageBox.Show("I am in View Model");
    }

    public void GetCurrentSongInfo()
    { 
        // Do stuff to get the current song playing
     }
}

 public class AlbumItem
 {
    public string Title {get;set;}
    public string Artist {get;set;}
    public BitmapImage AlbumArt {get;set;}

    public AlbumItem(Album)
    {
       this.Title = Album.Name;
       this.Artist = Album.Artist.Name;

       if(Album.HasArt)
       {
           BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
           bmp.SetSource(Album.GetAlbumArt());

           AlbumArt = bmp;
       }
    }        
 }
```

Now if I connect my phone to my PC and debug the application I see the `MessageBox` appear as it should.

If I then close the debugger, unplug my phone and then run the application on the phone I see that the `MessageBox` appears twice! Why does it appear twice?

Edit:
I believe I have solved my problem but if anyone could tell me why, it would be great. First I updated my code above to give a bit more details on what I was doing. Then I modified that code to look like this.

```
Public MainViewModel()
{
    if(IsInDesignMode)
    {
        // blah blah
    }
    else
    {       
        MessageBox.Show("I am in View Model");
    }

    public void GetMusic()
    { 
       MediaLibrary ml = new MediaLibrary();
       Songs = ml.Songs;
       ArtisList = ml.Artists;
       PlayLists = ml.Playlists;

       foreach(Album a in ml.Albums)
            MyAlbums.Add(new AlbumItem(a));

        GetCurrentSongInfo();
    }

    public void GetCurrentSongInfo()
    { 
        // Do stuff to get the current song playing
    }
}

 public class AlbumItem
 {
    public string Title {get;set;}
    public string Artist {get;set;}
    public BitmapImage AlbumArt {get;set;}

    public AlbumItem(Album)
    {
       this.Title = Album.Name;
       this.Artist = Album.Artist.Name;

       if(Album.HasArt)
       {
           BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
           bmp.SetSource(Album.GetAlbumArt());

           AlbumArt = bmp;
       }
    }        
 }
```

Then in the Page.Loaded Event I would do this.

```
void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{    
    mvm.GetMusic();
}
```

This seems to have solved the problem, although a new issue has occurred which I will post in a separate question.

Comment: Looks like you may be creating two instances of the ViewModel...

Comment: Which is what I thought but why, when debugging through the PC, is only one instance being created?